# Unable to upload a file to server in android?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a problem with uploading file to the server. Here i'm trying to create the registration form.

I need to upload all values that taken from user, along with that i need to upload the resume resume is in PDF format.

Here is my code. Please look into it.

```
      public String serverResponse(String mFilePath){
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost poster = new HttpPost(mUrl);

        File resume = new File(mFilePath);  //Actual file from the device
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entity.addPart("name", new StringBody("name"));
        entity.addPart("phone", new StringBody("1234567890"));
        entity.addPart("attachment", new FileBody(resume));
        poster.setEntity(entity);

        return client.execute(poster, new ResponseHandler<String>() {
            public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

                return EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
            }
        });
      }
```

The problem is above code works when i send the data to url(**"http://www.example.com"**), and it doesn't works on the url(**"https://www.example.com"**).

can anyone tell what's wrong on my code.

Please help me on this.

**Edit :**  I checked the request from android in server side, there i found empty data in request and it response back with default message(response that set in server).

`so my request hits the server with empty values. Is problem in my code (or) server side ?`

just now i checked, that this same URL works fine in website.

Please direct me in correct way if i was wrong

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess, maybe your `https` url is not signed with a ssl certificate and the server might be responding with `SSLHandshakeException`. Check your stacktrace if you're getting any exception

Comment: but i send the data(without file) to server with same domain and it works. You said that SSL is not signed in server can you direct me with reference link.

Comment: @sripadRaj I have updated my question, see my edit

Comment: I'm not sure, cant say if your code is wrong or its server side problem. Surround your code with try catch block, check if you're getting any exception. Check your response codes from server as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this code i hope this will help you.

```
public String uploadFile(String filePath, String name, String phone, String url) throws Exception {

        String crlf = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
            httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
            httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            File file = new File(filePath);
            if (file != null) {
                httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

                outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();

                outputStream.write((crlf + twoHyphens + boundary + crlf).getBytes());
                outputStream.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"" + crlf + crlf + name).getBytes());
                outputStream.write((crlf + twoHyphens + boundary + crlf).getBytes());
                outputStream.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phone\"" + crlf + crlf + phone).getBytes());
                outputStream.write((crlf + twoHyphens + boundary + crlf).getBytes());

                Log.e("Response :", "Response Code : " + file.getName());

                outputStream.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""
                        + file.getName()
                        + "\""
                        + crlf
                        + "Content-Type: image/jpeg" + crlf).getBytes());

                outputStream.write(crlf.getBytes());

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;

                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                outputStream.write(crlf.getBytes());
                outputStream.write((twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf).getBytes());

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                fis.close();
            }

            httpUrlConnection.connect();

            Log.e("Response :", "Response Code : " + httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode());

            if (httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() == -1) {

                onImageUploadCompleted.onImageUploadCompleted("error -1");
                Log.e("Connection error", "Connection error: url " + url);
                String json = "{\"error\": {\"code\": 991, \"message\": \"Connection error: `991`\"}}";
            }

            if (httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() == 204) {
                return "Upload failed";
            }
            if (httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            }
            else
                inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream();

            in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            int read;

            char[] buff = new char[1024];

            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                sb.append(buff, 0, read);
            }

            File f = new File(filePath);
            f.delete();
            Log.e("Response ", "Response text : " + sb.toString());

            if (httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                //ParseJson.parseException(sb.toString());
                Log.e("Failed", "Failed safe : " + sb.toString());
                return sb.toString();
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }

            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }

            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpUrlConnection != null) {
                httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: will try this and let you know

Comment: its not working, I've updated my question,please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to post a file.Should be used in background thread, and function will return the server response.

```
    public String postFile(String mFileName,String apiUrl,String fileType,HashMap<String,String> params) throws Exception{

    String output = "null";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())
            + "*****";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";

    String result = "";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize, bytesTransffered, bytesTotals;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 10;

    String[] q = mFileName.split("/");
    int idx = q.length - 1;


    File file = new File(mFileName);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    Log.d(TAG, "msg is " + q[idx]);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
            + "file" + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] + "\"" + lineEnd);

    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + fileType + lineEnd);

    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"
            + lineEnd);

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    long bytesTotal = file.length();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    bytesTransffered = 0;
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesTransffered = bytesRead;
    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesTransffered += bytesRead;
        if (mProgressUpdateListener != null) {
            publishProgress((100 * bytesTransffered)
                    / Integer.parseInt(bytesTotal + ""));

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Progress Listener is Null");
        }
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    Iterator it = params.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String key= (String) pair.getKey();
        String value = (String) pair.getValue();
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(value);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);

    }

    Log.d(TAG,"Response code "+connection.getResponseCode());
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));
        output = "";
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            output += line;
        }


    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: i tried this too, and it is similar to @MustanserIqbal answer. I have updated my question please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Use Retrofit to uplaod a file.
It is faster and easy

Create an interface

public interface ApiClient {

```
@Multipart
@POST(NetworkUtils.UPLOAD_PHOTO_URL)
Call<PhotoResponseModel> uploadPhoto(
        @Header("id") String id,
        @Header("imageId") String imageId,
        /*@Part("description") RequestBody description,*/
        @Part MultipartBody.Part photo);
```

}

call this method

public void syncPhoto() 
{

```
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NetworkUtils.SERVER_PATH)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    ApiClient apiClient = retrofit.create`(ApiClient.class);

    RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(/*MediaType.parse(context.getContentResolver().getType(Uri.parse(photoDetails.getImageUrl())))*/
            MediaType.parse("image/*"),
            file);

    MultipartBody.Part fileMultiPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", file.getName(), filePart);

    Call<PhotoResponseModel> call = apiClient.uploadPhoto(id, imageId, fileMultiPart);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotoResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PhotoResponseModel> call, Response<PhotoResponseModel> response) {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PhotoResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", "onFailure: ");
        }
    });


}
```

Add dependencies to gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

check this link
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server